# Match hex color inside square brackets

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a hex color inside a BBCode color tag and only the color, but having trouble isolating just the color.

Sample BBCode:

```
[b][color=#ffffff]test text[/color][/b]
```

The best regex I've been able to come up with is this:

```
/\[[^[]*?(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})[^]]*?\]/
```

It matches the opening color tag and only it, but I was hoping for something more specific. I've been trying to use some positive lookaheads and lookbehinds, but am getting nowhere quick.

```
/(?=\[)(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})(?<=\])/
```

I'm hoping to get it down to just #ffffff as the entire matched section, but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `\[color=\#(.*)\]\b` ? (*as horrible as it is ahhhhh*)

Comment: There can be spaces in between sometimes so I was hoping to avoid basing is around color.

Answer (score 0):

`/#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}/`

Edited for comment

Comment: I need to match the hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
(?<=\[color=)(#[a-f0-9]{3,6})(?=\])
```

Use a lookbehind (`(?<=\[color=)`), a capturing group for the color (`(#[a-f0-9]{3,6})`), and a lookahead (`(?=\])`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/color=#([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})/
```

That finds anything with `color=` and a hex color code.

Hope this works.